# Copying an object with attachments from a distributed database to a distributed one

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-server, enterprise-geodatabase, python-addin, map-service

I wrote a addins to transfer selected objects from one distributed database to another. Each layer participates in a geographic service (MapService).
The program works successfully sometimes, and sometimes it hangs for a long time and nothing happens. Any suggestions on how to make the script work stable?

```py
# -*- coding: cp1251 -*-
import arcpy
import pythonaddins
import sys

class CopyToArchiv(object):
    """Implementation for script_addin.CopyToArchiv (Button)"""
    def __init__(self):
        self.enabled = True
        self.checked = False
        
            
    def onClick(self):
        
        global staticVal # the first layer with attachments
        global staticVal_arch # the second layer to archive the objects from the first layer
        
        arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True
        
        mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument('current')
        layer1 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(staticVal)
        layer2 = arcpy.mapping.Layer(staticVal_arch)

        staticVal_arch_f=layer2.datasetName
        #workspace
        worksps1=layer1.dataSource[:(layer1.dataSource.lower()).find(".sde")]+".sde\\"
        worksps2=layer2.dataSource[:(layer2.dataSource.lower()).find(".sde")]+".sde\\"
        
        field_names2 = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(layer2)]
        if "ID_SAVE" in field_names2:
            pass
        else:
            answer = pythonaddins.MessageBox(u'There is no ID_SAVE field! Add?', u'Message', 4)
            if answer == 'Yes':
                arcpy.AddField_management(layer2,"ID_SAVE","LONG")
            else:
                pythonaddins.MessageBox(u'Exit', u'Message', 0)
                sys.exit()
            
        #calculate field ID_SAVE=lID
        arcpy.CalculateField_management(layer2,"ID_SAVE","!OBJECTID!","PYTHON")

        #check the ID numbers of selected objects 
        list_GID=''
        with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(layer1, "OBJECTID") as cursor:
            for row in cursor:
                list_GID=list_GID+str(row[0])+','
        list_GID=list_GID[:len(list_GID)-1]
        list_GID='('+list_GID+')'
        
        #copy objects from one layer to another
        fieldmappings = arcpy.FieldMappings()
        fieldmappings.addTable(layer2)
            
        fieldmap = fieldmappings.getFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("ID_SAVE"))
        fieldmap.addInputField(layer1, "OBJECTID")
        fieldmappings.replaceFieldMap(fieldmappings.findFieldMapIndex("ID_SAVE"), fieldmap)

        arcpy.Append_management(layer1,layer2,"NO_TEST",fieldmappings)
        
        layer2_attach=worksps2+layer2.datasetName+"__ATTACH"
        layer1_attach=worksps1+layer1.datasetName+"__ATTACH"
        try:
            arcpy.Delete_management("layer1_attach")
        except arcpy.ExecuteError: 
            msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2) 
            pythonaddins.MessageBox(msgs, u"Error", 0)

        arcpy.MakeTableView_management(layer1_attach,"layer1_attach","REL_OBJECTID in " + list_GID)

        arcpy.Append_management("layer1_attach", layer2_attach, "NO_TEST")

        try:
            arcpy.Delete_management("layer2_attach")
        except arcpy.ExecuteError: 
            msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2) 
            pythonaddins.MessageBox(msgs, u"Error", 0)
            
        arcpy.MakeTableView_management(layer2_attach,"layer2_attach")
        arcpy.AddJoin_management("layer2_attach","REL_OBJECTID",layer2,"ID_SAVE","KEEP_COMMON")

        #calculate in attachments2 rel_ID=ID(from layer2)
 
        arcpy.CalculateField_management("layer2_attach", "REL_OBJECTID", "!" + staticVal_arch_f + ".OBJECTID!", "PYTHON")
        #удаляем связь
        arcpy.RemoveJoin_management("layer2_attach")
        #
        try:
            arcpy.Delete_management("layer1_attach")
            arcpy.Delete_management("layer2_attach")
        except arcpy.ExecuteError: 
            msgs = arcpy.GetMessages(2) 
            pythonaddins.MessageBox(msgs, u"Error", 0)
```

Comment: You need to give an indication of where the error occurs. Please [Edit] the Question.

Comment: @Vince thete is no errors. Just too long script execution sometimes and ArcMap hangs. Сould it be due to the fact that the layer participates in the dynamic MapService or that several users are using these layers?

Comment: You don't give an indication of *where* it hangs, or what *too long* means.

Comment: It works successful or it hangs until you close the project.